# Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, maui

Возникает ошибка при вызове команды. Запускал этот код на WPF все нормально, а на MAUI выдает эту ошибку.

```
private void createQuestionCheckBoxItems()
        {
            AddAnyQuestion(new CheckBoxItem());
        }
```

Вызываемый метод

```
private void AddAnyQuestion<T>(T item)
            where T : IItem, new()
        {
            Question question = new();
            question.Items.Add(item);
            Questions.Add(question); // ошибка возникает при выполнении этой строки
        }
```

Коллекция

```
public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
            = new ObservableCollection<Question>();
```

Класс Question

```
public class Question
    {
        private string questionName;
        public string QuestionName
        {
            get => questionName;
            set => questionName = value;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<IItem> Items { get; set; }
        = new ObservableCollection<IItem>();
    }
```

```
public interface IItem
    {
        bool Compare(object obj);
    }
```

```
public class CheckBoxItem : IItem
    {
        private string text;
        public string Text
        {
            get => text;
            set => text = value;
        }

        private bool correctAnswer = false;
        public bool CorrectAnswer
        {
            get => correctAnswer;
            set => correctAnswer = value;
        }

        public bool Compare(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is CheckBoxItem cb)
            {
                if (correctAnswer == cb.correctAnswer)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Предположу что Question не имплементирует IItem, что заявлено для AddAnyQuestion метода.

Comment: Не помогло, это ограничение стоит только на входной параметр, к объекту Question это недолжно иметь отношения

Comment: Решил проблему.

Comment: Каким образом решил?

Comment: По стеку вызовов ошибка начиналась с команды и заканчивалась в методе  указанной выше, что приводило к мысли о том, что проблема в бэкенде, но подробнее изучив maui, я выяснил что мной был неправильно составлен ListView.ItemTemplate. Я не использовал ViewCell что приводило к этой ошибке, но странно что ошибка в стеке вызовов никак не указывала на этот момент